# Kotlin by Lazy in Custom Views

Tags: android, kotlin

Currently, using `by Lazy` in a custom view break its visualisation in Android Studio. Using `isEditMode` can't be used because it is only available inside a method and not at variable initialisation scope. only workaround is using lateinit and or Delegates.notNull().

Is there any workaround for this?

Example:

```
class ImageViewCircleBg : ImageView {

    private var circleBgColor = R.color.colorPrimary
    private val paint by lazy {
        Paint().apply {
            style = Paint.Style.FILL
            isAntiAlias = true
        }
    }

    constructor(context: Context) : this(context, null)
    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?) : this(context, attrs, 0)
    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyleAttr: Int) : super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {

        val ta = context.theme.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.ImageViewCircleBg, 0, 0)
        circleBgColor = ta.getColor(R.styleable.ImageViewCircleBg_roundBgColor, circleBgColor)
        ta.recycle()

        this.paint.color = circleBgColor
    }
```

Produces the following error in android studio design window:

```
The following classes could not be instantiated:
- ....ImageViewCircleBg (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
 Tip: Use View.isInEditMode() in your custom views to skip code or show sample data when shown in the IDE  Exception Details java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found class kotlin.Lazy, but interface was expected   at ...ImageViewCircleBg.getPaint(ImageViewCircleBg.kt:-1)
```

Replacing by lazy with this:

```
private val paint: Paint

    init {
        paint = Paint().apply {
            style = Paint.Style.FILL
            isAntiAlias = true
        }
    }
```

Solves the problem.

Error:

```
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found class kotlin.lazy, but interface was expected
```

Comment: What do you mean by _break its visualisation_? Can you provide [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: sure, i'll update the answer